# use regex to exclude block comments from lines of code count

Tags: c++

I have a simple c++ program that simply counts the lines of code (LOC) of a given file.

I would like to use some sort of regex to exclude block comments (and possibly just simplify all of the condition in the if statement)

```
if (s[0] == '/' || s == "")
            {
                count--; //dont count lines of code of blank lines or comments
            }
```

currently it ommits single line comments with `/`'s or any blank lines, which is good. 
However, with block comments such as

```
/*
blank comment
blank comment
*/
```

my if statement only ommitts the `/*` because its begins with `/`, and doesnt ommit anything in between the block comment, so it thinks "blank comment" is a line of code and counts it...

EDIT:

here is what im trying to do, but not sure of the regex accuracy:

```
regex e ("\\n\\s*\\n"); this only addresses empty lines...how to address comments and multi-line comments?

if (regex_match (s[0],e))
{count--;}
```

Comment: why don't you take a shot at writing a regex and post that - asking questions about the specific problems with the regex.   Also, I suggest regex101.com for instant feedback while developing your regex.

Comment: @xaxxon check my question edit

Comment: A test should give you the answer regarding the accuracy (correctness?) of your RE.

Comment: Using regex here is error-prone. Have you considered embedded comment delimiters in literal strings? What about stuff like: `//*/*/*/*/*/*\\*\*\*`? Alternately, you could tell `gcc` or whatever other compiler to emit the post-preprocessor sources, which would have comments stripped (but macros expanded). Anyway, a toy parser is what you want to do this robustly. Just sayin'. TL;DR this is dont-parse-HTML-with-regex territory, even if it's not HTML.

Comment: @hacksalot does that address empty lines as well? it looks to me it addresses comments and multiline, but i dont see empty lines as well like \\n\\s*\\n